# Service not found for newly created binary

Tags: make, hostapd

I am running a Raspbian box, I ran a **make** cmd for a package I wished to compile - **hostapd**

After compiling I saw no errors and was left with a binary, I assume I must move this binary into

```
/usr/sbin/
```

I can see the binary is present and made sure the permissions were set correctly with

```
chmod 755 /usr/sbin/hostapd
```

When I try to call

```
service hostapd start
```

I get the following back

```
hostapd: unrecognized service
```

I am logged in as root and have tried rebooting the device, the problem still exists

Answer (score 1):

Issuing the `make install` command might install the Sys V init script in the correct location for you.

Comment: In my directory where I issued the **make install** cmd, After the compiling was complete the binary **hostapd** was left here, However running **service hostapd status** still returns **service unrecognized**, what do you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

`service` is used to control Sys V init scripts, which are located in /etc/init.d (typically). If you've built a daemon, you'll need to have an init script which will fire it up. (note: do not put the binary itself in /etc/init.d).

I'd expect there to be an init script somewhere in the source files. If not, you should be able to google around and find one.

Comment: I see, so do I move the binary into **/usr/sbin/** like I did but make or find the init script which I assume will point to that location?

Comment: `/usr/sbin` is fine, but you'll need a separate init script to start it and manage the PID file and such. Googling for 'hostapd init script' should give you some results.

Comment: it seems absolutly pathetic that people leave out the init.d scripts, is this a common thing? If I was to write my own hostapd init.d script what are the chances of the integrity being spot on? I have opened some of the other init.d scripts on my machine with nano and I can see they are not just simple 5 liners, they contain all sorts of if statements with msgs to output, how is ANYBODY supposed to know the inner workings of a binary?

Answer (score 0):

Was service(8) read?

OK, if it’s too long to be read, init scripts are located in `/etc/init.d/`, not `/usr/sbin/`.